# Flutter CachedNetworkImage Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider:classpath'

Tags: flutter, package

After adding the **CachedNetworkImage** dependency to my Flutter project and trying to *flutter run* using vscode (& Intellij..) the following exception was thrown:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider:classpath'.
   > Could not find sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.3.0/sdklib-26.3.0.jar
   > Could not find apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.3.0/apkzlib-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.3.0/apksig-3.3.0.jar
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I got the following dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.7
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
  flutter_riverpod: ^0.12.4
  http: ^0.12.2
  material_floating_search_bar: ^0.2.6
  shimmer: ^1.1.2
```

I'm using the latest pre-nullsafety versions, since I'm not ready for flutter 2.0 yet.

I don't think the blocked <dl.google.com> domain is the reason since I have the VPN on and can download the required jars externally..

If you got any insights on why I'm getting this error please share your ideas, I've been on it for the whole day :(

Comment: try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` and finally run project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few possible solutions for this problem:

1. Do a **flutter clean** on the terminal then **flutter pub get**.
2. or remove the version on the package from **cached_network_image: ^2.5.0** to **cached_network_image:**. Then do the 1st solution again (But try to avoid using this solution)

But if ever this 2 solutions would not work and you're goal is just caching images there is an alternative to this without using the **CachedNetworkImage** package.

**NetworkImage** class and **Image.network()** both do cached images.

Here's a link that might help you when you try **Image.network()**
: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oIAs-0G4mw

Comment: Of course I've tried clean then pub get before posting, but surprisingly today I tried the same and it just worked! I'll consider it an answer.